# php script, cannot apply command to a generated file

Tags: php, command-line, rename

I have a very simple code, but the final command I can not apply it to the generated file, I can not rename the file and I don't know why. it is not a renaming issue because if I change the renaming for `$cmd ="cp '$textfile''$file'"` or `$cmd ="mv '$textfile''$file'"`, it does not work either. I better explain it with the code:

```
<?php
// the original file to work with
$file = "COPYING.odt";

//change the extension of doc|pdf|docx|odt|rtf files to txt   
$txtfile = preg_replace('"\.(doc|pdf|docx|odt|rtf)$"', '.txt', $file);

//convert the odt file into txt and name it with the original name but txt extension
$cmd = "/usr/bin/unoconv -f txt '$file' -o '$textfile'";
shell_exec($cmd);

//store the file in the originals files folder
 rename("$file", "orig/$file");

//rename the generated txt file with the original name and extension "COPYING.odt"
rename("$textfile", "$file");


echo "conversion of file <em>$file</em> done";
?>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

**UPDATE** One thing I have forgoten to tell is that I apply this script to an uploaded file, so I can not give the static name of $file, but the variable $file.

**UPDATE 2** Following @AlanMachado suggestion I've changed **mv** command for **rename**, and this rename works but not the next.

Comment: Do you have the sufficient permissions to rename the file / write in the folder?

Comment: If what you want to do is [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) or even move the file, there is better, less-evil ways to do it in PHP than using `shell_exec`

Comment: Maybe you need to add the (relative or absolute) file path in the rename command?

Comment: @Expodat, yes actualy the previous two actions are accomplished.

Comment: @AlanMachado which one that would be?

Comment: @jtheman I've tried already but no success.

Comment: The one I linked in my comment, click on the `rename` word and you will see

Comment: @AlanMachado Yes, this is what I got at rename, I get that you say I should apply it also for moving the file, thanks, I will do it....

Comment: Remember the privilages used in this process are those that the webserver runs with, and not your personal privilages

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, the folder is writable to www-data and actually the previous operations to rename are well executed

Comment: @AlanMachado Yes as I say, the commands previous to rename are well applied by the www-data user on the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I've been three days with this script, that's why I ask the question in Stackoverflow, but just now I've realised that it is a TYPO error, yes:

```
$txtfile = preg_replace('"\.(doc|pdf|docx|odt|rtf)$"', '.txt', $file);
```

txtfile without e in txt, while

```
rename("$textfile", "$file");
```

textfile with e in text, I'm really sorry.

Anyway I don't know why the results of this command was the file with the right name:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/unoconv -f txt '$file' -o '$textfile'";
```